# cocos2d: Collision detection doesn't work right

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, collision

Hello every body i have a problem with collision detection.

i have the first method who add random objects

```
-(void)initObjects{

    int randomNumber = arc4random() % 5 + 1;

    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 1:
            [self initEnemy];
            CCLOG(@"Random number 1");
            break;

        case 2:
            [self initJetpack];
            break;

        case 3:
            [self initWine];
            break;

        case 4:
          //  [self initNight];
            break;

        default:
            CCLOG(@"no number");
            break;
    }

}
```

then when will choose the method born the object and if will collision detect delete the sprite added

the code into every objects method

```
[self schedule:@selector(collision) interval:1 / 60];
```

the collision method:

```
-(void)collision {
  if (CGRectIntersectsRect([_hero boundingBox], [_enemy boundingBox])) {
        CCLOG(@"Enemy collision intercect");
        [self spriteMoveFinished:_enemy]; // It's method like  [self removeChild:_enemy cleanup:YES];
        [self unschedule:@selector(collision)];
    }   else if (CGRectIntersectsRect([_hero boundingBox], [_powerNight boundingBox])) {
        CCLOG(@"PowerNight collision intercect");
       // the same up
    } else if (CGRectIntersectsRect([_hero boundingBox], [_wine boundingBox])) {
         CCLOG(@"Wine collision intercect");
       // the same up
    } else if (CGRectIntersectsRect([_hero boundingBox], [_jetPack boundingBox])) {
        CCLOG(@"Jetpack collision intercect");
        //the same up
    }
 }
```

now the interesting log

JetPack inizializated
Wine collision intercect(?????????) why wine??

enemy inizializated
Jetpack collision intercect (????? ) why jetPack??

**But sometimes it's ok**

enemy inizializated
enemy collision intercect

Where i wrong?

thank you every body cheers

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, it would be good to check for the existence of each of these objects before attempting to check collisions. For instance:

```
if (_jetPack) {  // Check if jetPack exists
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect([_hero boundingBox], [_jetPack boundingBox])) {

    }
}
```

This way, things are more clear and secure, and might fix your problem as well.

Comment: its good idea but doesn't work and i cant answer u for my no reputation

Comment: comments are the correct way to communicate. dont write an answer when it is really a question or a comment ;)

Comment: @GabrieleCarbonai: But that's unlikely - it means you *did* initialize those objects, when you shouldn't have. Perhaps you will have to show us more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

yes omega you are right, in the first i committed an error.

the sprite are in CCSpriteBatchNode and i called like this:

`[self addChild:nameSprite];`

i changed like this (original code)

```
self.jetPack = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"jetpack-4.png"];       
_jetPack.position = ccp(480, randomNumber);
[_batchNode addChild:_jetPack z:3 tag:3];
```

now i try many possibility and i change the collision method

```
-(void)collision:(ccTime)dt andTag:(int)tag {


if (_enemy){

    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_enemy.boundingBox, _hero.boundingBox)) { 
        CCLOG(@"Enemy collision intercect");
        [self spriteMoveFinished:_enemy andTag:6];
        [self unschedule:@selector(collision)];
    }
}// Continue with another collision
```

I wanted try width "tag" but doesn't work

the method where born the sprite call the collision

```
[self schedule:@selector(collision:andTag:) interval:1/60];
```

in the init method there is called method objects generator with random number

```
     [self schedule:@selector(initObjects) interval:8];
```

the sprites have time for died

in the log it's always the same

born the sprite correctly, and when there is some collision sometimes is good and sometimes no.

it's like the simulatore confuses the sprite, but the strange is:

if the sprite is _jetPack i have structure control if-else how is possible that sprite go into the _enemy collision??

i hope i am explained well.

thank you